# Error when trying upload .AAB to Google Play Console (res/values-fb)

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

When I compile an .AAB using 5.9.0 or newest Facebook Android SDK, and try to upload it in Google Play Console, an error happens.

> Your App Bundle targets the following unrecognized languages: fb. The
>   list of supported language codes can be found in the IANA registry.
>   Invalid languages caused by third-party libraries can be excluded
>   using the resConfigs Gradle property.

I think it's because a folder named 'values-fb', that's a folder which have some files, usually used to translations. But, this 'fb' isn't a language allowed by IANA.org.
https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

There's some fix?

Answer (score 8):

To me happened the same error I added in defaultConfig language

```
 defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "en", "US"
    }
```

Comment: Good, but I change the version to 5.8.0 and it works!

Comment: @AndréGuedes which version we need to change 5.8.0?

Answer (score 1):

Set bundle.language.enableSplit to FALSE.

This specifies that the app bundle should not support configuration APKs for language resources. These resources are instead packaged with each base and feature APK. For more details, see: [Disable config apks](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base#disable_config_apks)

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has fixed this issue if you update to version v5.11.2

Otherwise, you can change the version to 5.8.0 to avoid the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

***You don't need to anything just update the facebook version. thats it.***